# UIButton inside UITableViewCell not receiving taps?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have this bookmark button inside a table view:
[image]
[image]

And for some reason it is not responding to touches. I have a plain IBOutlet with a print statement that is never called. However, when I tap on the bookmark the cell does not act as if it is clicked. However, when I tap the bookmark the cell does not act as if it was clicked. It therefore seems to me like the system knows that the button should be receiving the taps (not the cell) but the IBOutlet doesn't work. Any ideas? User interaction is enabled for both the button and its superviews.

Comment: You need an IBAction not IBOutlet to do stuff on interaction with the button.

Comment: can you share your app screenshot which contain that cell and show your connection with cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add target to Bookmark button in **cellForRowAtIndexPath()** method and do whatever you wants to do on clicking on Bookmark button
 forExample :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellReuseIdentifier")
    cell.Bookmark.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tapBookMark(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}


func tapBookMark(_ sender: UIButton) {
     print('bookMark tapped')
}
```